# Java locking in one thread, unlocking in another

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to lock class objects (which handles a socket connection) and pass those objects to threads for processing.

```
public class Client{

    protected Socket socket;
    ...
    public Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

}
```

I have a simple worker class that handles the work.

```
public class ClientWriterWorker extends Runnable{

    protected Client client;
    protected String data;

    public ClientWriterWorker(Client client, String data){
        this.client = client;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        // do the processing
        this.client.write(this.data);
        // release the lock?
        this.client.lock.unlock(); // does not work
    }

}
```

Then I have a loop that gets unlocked client, locks it, and passes it to thread.

```
Client currentClient = null;
while(true){
    for(Client client : clients){
        if(client.lock.tryLock()){
             // we have the lock
             currentClient = client;
             break;
        }
    }
    if(currentClient != null){
        break;
    }
}
new Thread(new ClientWriterWorker(currentClient, "some data")).start();
```

Is it possible to unlock locks in another thread? Is my design flawed?

Comment: Even if Java let you do that, it goes against the principle of a lock. A lock is meant to be held by a thread that does stuff to it's object, and when it's done, releases the object for other threads to do the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavioral specification of [`ReentrantLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) specifies that it must be unlocked by the thread that locked it. This makes sense, because the whole purpose of this lock implementation is to track which thread locked it so that it can re-lock it as many times as it wants (reentrancy). Quoting parts of the documentation:

> ```
> public void unlock()
> ```
>
> Attempts to release this lock.
>
> If the current thread is the holder of this lock then the hold count is decremented. If the hold count is now zero then the lock is released. If the current thread is not the holder of this lock then IllegalMonitorStateException is thrown.

---

It is definitely possible for you to implement your own `Lock` class that can be locked and unlocked from any thread. Here is one partial answer:

```
public class MyLock implements java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock {

    private boolean isLocked = false;

    public synchronized void lock() throws InterruptedException {
        while (isLocked)
            wait();
        isLocked = true;
    }

    public synchronized void unlock() {
        if (!isLocked)
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        isLocked = false;
        notify();
    }    

}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to write your own class, you can use a [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html).

From the documentation page:

> A semaphore initialized to one, and which is used such that it only
>   has at most one permit available, can serve as a mutual exclusion
>   lock. This is more commonly known as a binary semaphore, because it
>   only has two states: one permit available, or zero permits available.
>   **When used in this way, the binary semaphore has the property (unlike
>   many Lock implementations), that the "lock" can be released by a
>   thread other than the owner (as semaphores have no notion of
>   ownership).** This can be useful in some specialized contexts, such as
>   deadlock recovery.

Just initialize the semaphore with 1 permit:

```
semaphore = new Semaphore(1);
```

Then use `semaphore.acquire()` and `semaphore.release()` instead of `lock.lock()` and `lock.unlock()`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use monitors? https://www.python.org/~jeremy/monitor.py they have the ability to broadcast/wakeup other sleeping threads once they have finished.

Here's a link http://www.csc.villanova.edu/~mdamian/threads/javamonitors.html that explains how to use them in java

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you should rethink your problem.

Commonly you use pools of *something* (threads, connections, whatever) and whenever a *something* is needed a call to the pool provider object gives out a reference to the requested object. Until that object is returned to the pool (by calling the unlocking method), no further locking is required, because the whole idea is that the object is now exclusively owned by the thread that requested it from the pool (and the pool will not give out that object again before it has been returned by the owning thread).

In this pattern there is typically a single lock (for the pool) often implemented by simply synchronizing on the pool object (or a dedicated lock object). The only methods that do locking and unlocking are all found on the pool (obtain() and release()). The managed objects themselves don't contain any locking.

In the very simplest of versions it could look like this:

```
class MyResource {
     // represents the managed resources
}

class MyPool {
     private List<MyResource> available = new ArrayList<>();

     public synchronized MyResource obtain() {
         MyResource result = available.isEmpty()
             ? new MyResource() : available.remove(0);
         return result;
     }

     public synchronized void release(MyResource resource) {
         available.add(resource);
     }
}
```

Obviously I omitted all code use to actually initialize the pool and you may want to handle the case that there isn't a resource available differently (e.g. by waiting until one becomes available instead of creating a new one).

A variation of this is to have the resource class have a reference to its pool and move the release() method onto the resource class; which in turn calls a non-public method on the pool to do the actual release.

With a little planning effort lock-free versions of this pattern can be implemented using AtomicReference's compareAndSet() method to manage the pool contents without even synchronizing anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Use case:

- Application Layer uses concurrency and a data Link layer needs a MAC

To wait for an async response, or to do atomic actions, I am using:

```
    volatile CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    
    private void commsWaitForResponse() {
        try {
            latch.await(3500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                if (latch.getCount() < 1) {
                    //create new latch
                    latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    
    private void commLockRelease() {
            latch.countDown();
        }
```